# This question is about an exercise in the book Eloquent JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, object

The last part to this exercise is to write a recursive function that takes two parameters, a joined list and an index respectively. The function will find the value in the object within the list at it's respective index. The code i have written works the way i want (i can see it working when i console.log for every occasion the function is called. But on the last occasion it refers undefined as my value. I cannot understand why. Oh and it works for index of 0. code as followed.

and first, list looks like this:

```
list = {
    value: 1,
    rest: {
        value: 2,
        rest: {
            value: 3,
            rest: null
            }
        }
    };



   const nth = (list, targetNum) => {
   let value = Object.values(list)[0];
   if (targetNum == 0) {
       return value;
   } else {
       targetNum = targetNum -1;
       list = Object.values(list)[1];
    //    console.log(value);
    //    console.log(targetNum);
    //    console.log(list);
       nth(list, targetNum);
   }
};
console.log(nth(arrayToList([1,2,3]),2));
```

below is the code for arrayToList it was the first part of the exercise and if you have any comments that's cool, cause the hints ended up suggesting to build the list from the end.

```
const arrayToList = (arr) => { 
    let list = {
        value: arr[0],
        rest: nestObject()
    };
    function nestObject() {
        let rest = {};
        arr.shift();
        const length = arr.length;
        if (length == 1) {
            rest.value = arr[0];
            rest.rest = null;
        } else {
            rest.value = arr[0];
            rest.rest = nestObject();
        }
        return rest;   
    }
    return list;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to add a `return` when recursively calling `nth`. Otherwise the logic is carried out but no value is returned (unless `targetNum` is 0)

```
const nth = (list, targetNum) => {
   let value = Object.values(list)[0];
   if (targetNum == 0) {
       return value;
   } else {
       targetNum = targetNum -1;
       list = Object.values(list)[1];
       return nth(list, targetNum); // return needed here too
   }
};
```

Or more succinctly:

```
const nth = (list, n) => n === 0 ? list.value : nth(list.rest, n - 1)
```

Here's another non-recursive `arrayToList` that builds the list from the end:

```
const arrayToList = arr => arr.slice().reverse().reduce((rest, value) => ({value, rest}), null);
```

(The `slice` here is just to make a copy of the array so that the original is not reversed in place.)

Comment: oh i see, it's not enough to call the function, you actually have to return the call to function as a value. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Both solutions are convoluted and unnecessary verbose. Actually, both functions could be one-liners. Here are a few hints:

For the `toList` thing consider the following:

- if the input array is empty, return `null` (base case)
- otherwise, split the input array into the "head" (=the first element) and "tail" (=the rest). For example, `[1,2,3,4] => 1 and [2,3,4]`
- return an object with `value` equal to "head" and `rest` equal to `toList` applied to the "tail" (recursion)

On a more advanced note, the split can be done right in the function signature with destructuring:

```
const toList = ([head=null, ...tail]) => ...
```

Similarly for `nth(list, N)`

- if `N` is zero, return `list.value` (base case)
- otherwise, return an application of `nth` with arguments `list.rest` and `N-1` (recursion)

Again, the signature can benefit from destructuring:

```
const nth = ({value, rest}, n) =>
```

Full code, if you're interested:

```js
const toList = ([value = null, ...rest]) =>
    value === null
        ? null
        : {value, rest: toList(rest)}

const nth = ({value, rest}, n) =>
    n === 0
        ? value
        : nth(rest, n - 1)

//

let lst = toList(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])
// or simply toList('abcdef')

console.log(lst)

console.log(nth(lst, 0))
console.log(nth(lst, 4))
```

Comment: yes, that is very nice. i wrote a version with the destructuring, you'd prob say it's still to verbose as it's not yet a one liner.   and the nth is similar logic. thank you.

Comment: @AnthonyT: I doesn't have to be on one line literally, by one-liner we usually mean "an arrow function that is a single short expression". I shared my variants in the hidden snippet in case you're interested.

Comment: I see. Thank you again. Yes, that it was i have written after reading your hints, just different syntax. I will look into how to use what you have written in the snippet. Seems to be what others use as well.

Answer (score 1):

[Georg’s recursive solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67187995/3617380) are beautiful!

I’d like to add the hinted “build the list from the end” solution from [the book](https://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html#i_nSTX34CM1M):

```js
const arrayToList => (arr) => {
  var list
  while (arr.length) {
    list = {value: arr.pop(), rest: list}
  }
  return list
}
```

Comment: @AnthonyT There isn't a complete solution in the book. It only gives a one-liner hint that goes `list = { value: X, rest: list }`. I expand that into a full solution.

Comment: this looks a little different from the solution in the book. i'm still trying to figure out how yours logs everything backwards, and how yours could be manipulated to have rest: null, instead of undefined in the deepest nested object.

Comment: and yeah on the phone there is actually a section with full solutions :)

Comment: I use `arr.pop()` which returns element from the end of the array, thus backwards. To have `rest: null`, you just initialize `var list = null` that's it.

Comment: oh i see how it's working backwards now, pretty cool, thank you.